# gtk-need a scrolled list within a tab

Tags: c, linux, tabs, listbox, gtk

I need a scrolled list within a tab.
I searched in google and framed this code from some examples. But it is not compiling or working fine.

My code is as follows

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gint delete( GtkWidget *widget,
             GtkWidget *event,
             gpointer   data )
{
    gtk_main_quit();
    return(FALSE);
}


static void activate1(GtkApplication * app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget* window=0;
    GtkWidget* notebook = 0;
    GtkWidget* frame = 0;
    GtkWidget *grid = 0, *grid2 = 0;
    GtkWidget* scrolled_window = 0;

 GtkWidget *label = 0;
 char bufferf[32] = "Append Frame 1";
    char bufferl[32] = "Page 1";

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"Security Alert");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),200,200);
 //gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

   // window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    //gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (window), "delete_event",
    //                    GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (delete), NULL);

    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    //table = gtk_table_new(3,6,FALSE);

    grid = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

/* Create a new notebook, place the position of the tabs */
    notebook = gtk_notebook_new ();
    gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), GTK_POS_TOP);
    //gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), notebook, 0,6,0,1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), notebook, 0, 6, 0, 1);
    gtk_widget_show(notebook);

/* create a new scrolled window. */
    scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);

    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), 10);

    /* the policy is one of GTK_POLICY AUTOMATIC, or GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS.
     * GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC will automatically decide whether you need
     * scrollbars, whereas GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS will always leave the scrollbars
     * there.  The first one is the horizontal scrollbar, the second,
     * the vertical. */
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window),
                                    GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS);
    /* The dialog window is created with a vbox packed into it. */
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (GTK_DIALOG(window)->vbox), scrolled_window,
                        TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (notebook), scrolled_window);

    gtk_widget_show (scrolled_window);
//gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (
                   //GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), table);

    grid2 = gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), grid2);
        frame = gtk_frame_new (bufferf);
        gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), 10);
        //gtk_widget_set_usize (frame, 100, 75);
        gtk_widget_show (frame);

        label = gtk_label_new (bufferf);
        gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), label);
        gtk_widget_show (label);

        label = gtk_label_new (bufferl);

gtk_notebook_append_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), scrolled_window, label);
    //gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_widget_show(grid);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
}


int main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("com.SwuljPeepalTree.SecurityAlert", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate1), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;

}
```

I get compile error. Copied and pasted the error.
Can someone paste a better link. Why Google search does not return proper codes. Is Gtk deprecated. I searched for "GTK Tabs" to get the above code.

```
SecurityAlert.c: In function ‘activate1’:
SecurityAlert.c:61:52: error: ‘GtkDialog’ has no member named ‘vbox’
     gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (GTK_DIALOG(window)->vbox), scrolled_window, 
                                                    ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:1918:57: note: in definition of macro ‘_G_TYPE_CIC’
     ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
                                                         ^
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbox.h:40:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST’
 #define GTK_BOX(obj)            (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), GTK_TYPE_BOX, GtkBox))
                                  ^
SecurityAlert.c:61:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘GTK_BOX’
     gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (GTK_DIALOG(window)->vbox), scrolled_window,
```

Is there any example code?

Comment: there is.
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/book1.html
Its actually really good. Try to "read" all of it, took me a while as beginner to grasp the concept, its actually really simple when you know how to "use" it.

Comment: That link is for a GTK 2 tutorial, so I doubt it's the best reference. This is the closest to a GTK+ 3 tutorial: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

Made an fast and sloppy example
It looks like a 3 year old made it, but it compiles and "shows".

[image: Notebook widget with scrolledwindow children containing textview]

Found this git-repo that I mainly used as "reference"
https://github.com/Programmica/gtk3-tutorial/tree/master/_examples

*Update*
OP asked how to add something else then a "text"-widget.
Added example where I setup a treeview `init_tree()` and add that instead of `textview`

[image: Notebook widget with scrolledwindow children containing treeview]

Note that I simply commented out the textview-widget from the code and instead made a `gtk_container_add` with `init_tree()` instead.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}


GtkWidget * init_tree()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


  int count;
  gchar *text;

  for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
    {
      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);

      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

      gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolledwindow, -1, 200);

      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), scrolledwindow);
      GtkWidget *textview = gtk_text_view_new();
      /* gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), textview); */
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), init_tree());

      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
    }

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using the following:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gtk-test gtk-test.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: how to add contents to the scrolled window and clicking each item calls a function

Comment: the same way you are adding other GtkWidgets to a GtkWidget. Instead of add a gtk_text_view, you can add other GtkWidgets to the container
`gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), textview);`

Comment: can you look at he thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376895/gtk-listbox-contents-shown-in-middle-of-horizontal-line-listbox-does-not-fit-w

Comment: I followed your suggestion

Comment: one more last problem. I want when the item in the listbox is selected some processing to be done(some function called), the current tab display is hidden and new tab is displayed with the results and a back button. When Back button is pressed it does 2 cases for 2 tabs in 1 tab- it just shows the previous content in tab 2- it does processing again and shows results in list box in original format.

Comment: @chinmay here is the thing. In my example the same content is loaded in to every tab. You are free to load what ever you want to each tab.
What you want to do is; connect a callback function for what should happen when list item is clicked or what not. I believe you got plenty of examples, dont expect people to do your work for free.