# gtk-listbox -contents shown in middle of horizontal line, listbox does not fit window size

Tags: linux, listbox, gtk

I wrote a code for listbox in gtk
problems
1. the contents of listbox are shown in middle of horizontal line. I want it to be left aligned.
2. the listbox does not fit the window size
3.the list box is within a notebook tab. I want when the item in the listbox is selected some processing to be done(some function called), the current tab display is hidden and new tab is displayed with the results and a back button. When Back button is pressed it does 2 cases for 2 tabs
in 1 tab- it just shows the previous content
in tab 2- it does processing again and shows results in list box in original format.

my code is as follows

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


  int count;
  int i;
  gchar *text;

  for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
    {
      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);
      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), scrolledwindow);
      //GtkWidget *textview = gtk_text_view_new();
      GtkWidget *listbox = gtk_list_box_new();
      for (i=1; i<100; i++)
      {
          gchar *name = g_strdup_printf("Label %i", i);
          GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(name);
          gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(listbox), label);

 }
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), listbox);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), scrolledwindow);

      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
    }

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer to 1 and 2 it's all about alignment and expand properties.

1. You can set expand properties while adding to the container with `gtk_box_pack_*` set of functions, eg., [`gtk_box_pack_start`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-start).
2. You can set alignment with `gtk_widget_set_halign` and `gtk_widget_set_valign` functions

Applying these to your code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


  int count;
  int i;
  gchar *text;

  for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
  {
      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);
      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), scrolledwindow, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      GtkWidget *listbox = gtk_list_box_new();
      for (i=1; i<100; i++)
      {
          gchar *name = g_strdup_printf("Label %i", i);
          GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(name);
          gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET(label), GTK_ALIGN_START);
          gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(listbox), label);

      }
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), listbox);
      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
  }

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Notice `gtk_box_pack_start` when adding the scrolled window to the container, it's set to fill and expand.
Also check the label `halign` being set at GTK_ALIGN_START.

The result should be:

[image]

About 3) it's too specific and could not really understand your goal.
You should also separate questions so that the answers are specific to each problem.

Comment: Agree about the question. The op needs to break down the question into multiple small problems & ask about them separately. 
Your answer looks good to me.